# rendering svg in xamarin form resulting in black square

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to print svg pictures on my xamarin forms app.
I am using SkiaSharp.
I implemented a component using a Bindable property to get the byte[] of the svg and I draw it in the component.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Image), typeof(byte[]), typeof(SvgCanvas));
public byte[] Image
    {
        get => (byte[])GetValue(ImageProperty);
        set
        {
            if (Image == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            SetValue(ImageProperty, value);

            CanvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }
    }

private void OnPainting(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        int width = args.Info.Width;
        int height = args.Info.Height;

        // clear the surface
        canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

        // the page is not visible yet
        if (Image == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        SKSvg svg = new SKSvg(new SKSize(width, height));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Image))
        {
            svg.Load(ms);
        }

        // draw the svg
       // canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture, ref matrix);
        canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);
    }
```

It looks like the Picture is loaded but only a black square is displayed on my view...

My component is called like this in my page: (Picture is a byte[])

```
 <controls:SvgCanvas Image="{Binding Picture}" />
```

Did somebody had the same issue? Maybe an encoding problem?

I am kind of lost..

Comment: Try using [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) instead, it have support for svg images as you can read here [SVG support](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support)

Comment: I finaly found that the problem was css sstyle in my picture. Do you think FFLoading will support it? Or maybe there are tools to remove the style and "simplify' my svg?